Can not initialize pod and create the container due to deleted flannel name space
I am trying to run Spark connect on kubernets. The name spaces on my kebernetes as follow:
root@master-node:~# kubectl get namespaces
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   17h
kube-node-lease   Active   17h
kube-public       Active   17h
kube-system       Active   17h

I try to run a spark connect on kubernets as below:
./spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 --conf spark.ui.port=4041 --driver-memory 8g --master k8s://https://172.22.0.80:6443  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=apache/spark-py --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default

To get pods status
root@master-node:~# kubectl get pods -n default
NAME                                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          9m56s
spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          9m56s
root@master-node:~#

I am not sure why it always creat two pods and it is always remaing in ContainerCreating states
Describing the pod
root@master-node:~# kubectl describe pod spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1
Name:             spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             master-node/172.22.0.80
Start Time:       Mon, 04 Nov 2024 07:55:19 +0330
Labels:           spark-app-name=spark-connect-server
                  spark-app-selector=spark-9939557601604134993bed0957e51c4f

.....
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               10m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1 to master-node
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  10m                    kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed t
o set up sandbox container "4f3673b7b5451dfed45fa2ed5cd230bbaa64ddd997633f8933c052f20a1bfd36" network for pod "spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe
-exec-1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1_default" network: plugin type="flannel" failed (add): loadFlannelSubnetEnv failed: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  10m                    kubelet            
  Normal   SandboxChanged          5m56s (x241 over 10m)  kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  56s (x473 over 10m)    kubelet            (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error
: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "4c6bf46f5379300fed39f569d46c3bfa7e7c845ec11321b2618b3c15adce60ed" network for pod "spark
-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "spark-connect-server-1ab49692f56b85fe-exec-1_default" network: plugin type="flannel" failed (add): loadFlannelSubnetEnv failed: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory

It is giving me an error in regards to flannel name space. I have deleted those resources before and I am not sure why this error coming up. Resetting the and initializing the cluster doesn't resolve the error


Check if Flannel is running: Run this to check if Flannel pods are up and running:
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Look for anything with “flannel” in its name. If you don’t see any Flannel pods, Flannel might not be installed or could have been removed accidentally.

Restart Flannel pods: If Flannel pods are there but seem stuck or problematic, try deleting them to trigger a restart:
kubectl delete pod -n kube-system -l app=flannel

The system should restart Flannel, and this may regenerate the subnet.env file.

Check the Flannel ConfigMap: Flannel’s settings are stored in a ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace. You can check it with:
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system

If you don’t see anything related to Flannel, it could help to reapply the original Flannel setup file.

Reapply Flannel Configuration: Reapplying the Flannel configuration can fix missing files. You could use:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml


Check Node Readiness: Make sure all nodes are in Ready state. Sometimes, network or node issues can mess with Flannel’s ability to set up networking for pods.


These steps should hopefully get the Flannel networking working, so you can try starting Spark Connect again. Let me know if this helps or if there’s more info about what you’re seeing!

This is what it worked for me:
vim /run/flannel/subnet.env

FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.240.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.240.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true

Nevertheless, I don't have flannel apps anywhere in namespaces. Not sure why I had to do above!
